# Visual C# If text box equals 1 open form 1 if text box equals 2 open form 2

Tags: c#

Im creating a login page for my work at school but im a bit stuck, i need it so that if the student is logins in it shows the student form anf if a teacher logins in it shows the teacher form.

```
        private void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtUser.Text == "Student" & txtPass.Text == "GPSC1" || txtUser.Text == "Staff" & txtPass.Text == "GPSC2")

            MessageBox.Show("Success");

        else
            MessageBox.Show("Error");

        if (txtUser.Text == "Student" & txtPass.Text == "GPSC1")
            this.Hide();
        StudentForm studentForm = new StudentForm();
        studentForm.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();

        if (txtUser.Text == "Staff" & txtPass.Text == "GPSC2")
            this.Hide();
        TeacherForm teacherForm = new TeacherForm();
        teacherForm.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add braces to create a new scope, so you can execute more than one statement within an `if` statement.

For example:

```
private void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtUser.Text == "Student" && txtPass.Text == "GPSC1")
    //                            ^^  use &&   (& suits better for bitwise)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
        this.Hide();
        StudentForm studentForm = new StudentForm();
        studentForm.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
    else
        if(txtUser.Text == "Staff" && txtPass.Text == "GPSC2")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
            this.Hide();
            TeacherForm teacherForm = new TeacherForm();
            teacherForm.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```